# How to hide pager in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, pager

I'm using pager for paging with ListView, But the problem is, when there is no row found from the table. In that case, pagers paging also showing. So, my question is, how can i hide the pager. when ListView display the message `no row found` .

Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`DataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.databound.aspx) event to hide it:

```
protected void jobSearchResult_DataBound(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     DataPager pager = (DataPager)jobSearchResult.FindControl("jobSearchPager");
     pager.Visible = pager.TotalRowCount > pager.MaximumRows;
}
```

**Edit**: Assuming you're using VB.NET

```
Protected Sub jobSearchResult_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
    Dim pager = DirectCast(jobSearchResult.FindControl("jobSearchPager"), DataPager)
    pager.Visible = pager.TotalRowCount > pager.MaximumRows 
End Sub
```

If your pager is not part of the ListView's `LayoutTemplate`(f.e. outside of the ListView), you can reference it directly without using `FindControl`:

```
jobSearchPager.Visible = jobSearchPager.TotalRowCount > jobSearchPager.MaximumRows
```

- [DataPager.TotalRowCount Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datapager.totalrowcount.aspx)
- [DataPager.MaximumRows Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datapager.maximumrows.aspx)

Comment: i was trying the same.. but, getting error `Protected Sub jobSearchResult_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)


        DataPager pager = (DataPager) jobSearchResult.FindControl("jobSearchPager")
        pager.Visible = (pager.PageSize < pager.TotalRowCount)
    End Sub`

Comment: `DataPager' is a type and cannot be used as an expression` and `Name 'Pager' is not declared` and `Comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation expected.` and 5 others...

Comment: @coders_zone: Are you using C# or VB.NET? My answer is C# and your comment is a mix of both, hence won't compile in none.

Comment: @coders_zone: What does _not working_ mean? Another error, pager visible? Are you debugging to inspect pager.TotalRowCount and pager.MaximumRows?

Comment: pager still visible. Even, when i set `pager.Visible=False`. Then, also it is visible. Now, i'm  going for debugging as you suggested.

Comment: when this databound will be called, because, when i put the Msgbox inside the function. then, msgbox doesn't appears.

Comment: @coders_zone: ASP.NET has no MessageBox, use the debugger instead. Set a breakpoint in codebehind then inspect all values in the [quick watch window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyzbs7s2.aspx).

Comment: @coders_zone: Where have you set the breakpoint? Is the pager part of the ListView or outside? If the latter you can reference it directly(see my edit).

Comment: where, should i put this code, in Page_Load or in same function with DataBound. It works when, i put your code into the Page_Load, But the problem is `TotalRowCount` return 2 even there is no row.

Comment: @coders_zone: in `jobSearchResult_DataBound`. Are you sure that there are not records? You could also debug `jobSearchResult.DataSource` in the quick watch window to check this.

Comment: In table there are 2 records, but when i put some condition into my query to display all the records with particular condition, and no records found. But,`jobSearchPager.TotalRowCount` return 2.

Comment: @coders_zone: Where,when and how do you you filter the query? Perhaps after the ListView was databound? Then either do that directly or move the code above into Page_PreRender.

Answer (score 0):

In your data bind method you can check the item source count. If it is zero set the visibility of the pager to false.

Answer (score 0):

Check your retrieved data for results, and if empty call:

```
DataPager.Visible = false;
```